# Communication through 3 level components on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm new developing for React and clearly I'm struggling in how to pass data through components. I have created an example on CodePen to try to understand the flow. The example is just an example of a return a value from a modal to the main level.

I have these levels of hierarchy:

- Main

  - InsideComponent

    - Form

      - Input Field

Inside my main component I have a span that I would like to update when the text inside the input field is typed.

I'm using props to pass callbacks and return the value that I need.
So, Is there a better way to pass those changes to my Main level?

PS: I saw a lot of examples here on StackOverflow, but I couldn't see this example without Redux or Flux.

My code:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onUpdateLabel = this.onUpdateLabel.bind(this);
  }
  
  onUpdateLabel(value) {
    this.setState({ text: value });
  }
  
  render() {
    let value = this.state.text != '' ? this.state.text : 'Waiting...';
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Main</h1>
        <span class='label'>{value}</span>
        <hr />
        <Modal onUpdateLabel={this.onUpdateLabel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    this.props.text = 'Inside Component';
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Modal</h2>
        <Form onUpdateLabel={this.props.onUpdateLabel} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onClickButton = this.onClickButton.bind(this);
    this.onUpdateText = this.onUpdateText.bind(this);
  }
  
  onUpdateText(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }
  
  onClickButton() {
    this.props.onUpdateLabel(this.state.text);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Form</h3>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type something' onChange={this.onUpdateText} />
        <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) but as it is stated in the doc:

> It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React.

If you decide to still use it, you would write something like that:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = { // Define the child context
      onUpdateLabel: PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onUpdateLabel = this.onUpdateLabel.bind(this);
  }

  onUpdateLabel(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  getChildContext(){ // Return the wanted context
      return {
          onUpdateLabel: this.onUpdateLabel,
      }
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

and in your `Form`

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  static contextTypes = { // Define the available context
      onUpdateLabel: PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onClickButton = this.onClickButton.bind(this);
    this.onUpdateText = this.onUpdateText.bind(this);
  }

  onUpdateText(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  onClickButton() { // Retrieve it from context instead of props
    this.context.onUpdateLabel(this.state.text);
  }

  render(){...}
}
```

You define the context in the main element, and use it in one of the children.

Comment: Thanks!! I was looking for context, but I'm going to start a big system using react and I'm afraid to use context because what you also said, can change a lot in the future.

Comment: Well, if you aim to create a big system, take a look at Redux or MobX (which is lighter and maybe more accessible than Redux).

Answer (score 0):

Your method is alright you were calling

> e.target.value

where it's not present

```
onUpdateLabel(text) {
   this.setState({ text: text });
}
```

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onUpdateLabel = this.onUpdateLabel.bind(this);
  }
  
  onUpdateLabel(text) {
    this.setState({ text: text });
  }
  
  render() {
    let value = this.state.text != '' ? this.state.text : 'Waiting...';
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Main</h1>
        <span class='label'>{value}</span>
        <hr />
        <Modal onUpdateLabel={this.onUpdateLabel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    this.props.text = 'Inside Component';
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Modal</h2>
        <Form onUpdateLabel={this.props.onUpdateLabel} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
    this.onClickButton = this.onClickButton.bind(this);
    this.onUpdateText = this.onUpdateText.bind(this);
  }
  
  onUpdateText(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }
  
  onClickButton() {
    this.props.onUpdateLabel(this.state.text);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Form</h3>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type something' onChange={this.onUpdateText} />
        <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm updating the text value inside the change event and through the onClick I called the callback.

  `onUpdateText(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }
  
  onClickButton() {
    this.props.onUpdateLabel(this.state.text);
  }`

Comment: and i was referring to the method written in parent component